# Does Spring ignore generic type info on @Lookup injections?

Tags: java, spring

It seems that Spring lookup method injection ignores generic type info of method's result.

1. Is it Spring bug or feature?
2. How can I avoid this without qualifying bean name in @Lookup?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Lookup;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component abstract class Outer {

    interface A<T> {}

    @Component static class B implements A<String> {}

    @Component static class C implements A<Integer> {}

    final A<Integer> c1;
    Outer(A<Integer> c1) { this.c1 = c1; }

    @PostConstruct void test() {
        System.out.println(c1.getClass().getName()); // generic constructor argument - ok
        System.out.println(c2().getClass().getName()); // lookup by class - ok

        System.out.println(c3().getClass().getName()); // lookup by generic type - FAIL.
        // throws "expected single matching bean but found 2: outer.B,outer.C"
    }

    @Lookup abstract C c2();
    @Lookup abstract A<Integer> c3();
}
```

Spring version: 5.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Issue was [confirmed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26998). Should be fixed in 5.3.8